# Haskell Scotty and Angularjs: jsonData function stopped parsing json data sent with $http.post()

Tags: json, angularjs, haskell, scotty

I have a Haskell/Scotty app with Angularjs as frontend. It worked flawlessly with regards to JSON parsing. Then it suddenly stopped for no reason. It happend after some Scotty and its dependencies version bump.

There is not much error feed back from the scotty `jsonData` function which parses JSON body.
None of the POST requests from Angular work at the moment. I can't figure out what happened.
I don't know which code example would be useful as any JSON POSTs result with `jsonData - no parse` error. That's all I get. Here are some code examples.

This is the controller that passes the simple user name and password

```
.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, authS, $rootScope) {
  $scope.auth = {local: false, uname: "", pass: ""};
  $scope.login = function() {
    authS.login($scope.auth);
  }
  $scope.logout = function() {
    $rootScope.user.uname = "";
    authS.logout();
  }
```

This is the service that sends the POST request JSON data to Scotty backend

```
.factory('authS', function($http, $location, flashS, $rootScope) {
  return {
    login: function (d) {
      $http.post("/api/login", d)
      .success(function() {
        $rootScope.user.uname = d.uname;
        flashS.set("Login Success!", 'green');
        $location.path('/home');
      })
      .error(function() {
        flashS.set("Login Failure!", 'red', true);
      });
    })
```

This is modified Scotty route function to try and catch the exception error

```
post "/api/login" $ loginUser `rescue` \e -> do
    b <- decodeUtf8 <$> body
    error $ unpack $ mconcat [ "Error was: ", e, "\n"
                             , "Body was:  ", b, "\n"
                             ]
```

This is the actual `loginUser` function

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Manage user login
loginUser :: ActionD ()
loginUser = do
  j <- jsonData
  error "passed the problem ..."
  let h = jdataDoc j
      u = at "uname" h
      p = at "pass" h
      l = at "local" h
  a <- if l then authDB u p else liftIO $ authAD u p
  if a then putInSession "uname" u else status unauthorized401
```

Nothing goes beyond `j <- jsonData` line.

`jsonData` function crashes and the exception gives me

```
Error was: jsonData - no parse: 
Body was:
```

That's all I get. No useful error and not even the body to analyse.

If someone had a similar problems please help. Or maybe a suggestion on what could've gone wrong. As I said before it all worked perfectly before some stupid update.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Looks like I get an empty body. That's why json parse error is returned.

Changing the login function to this

```
loginUser :: ActionD ()
loginUser = do
  j <- body
  if not $ LBS.null j then error ("Body:" ++ (LBS.unpack j)) else error "No body"
```

Returns me an empty body.

At the same time looking at the payload from the Chrome console gives me normal body

Headers:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 0.0.0.0:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://0.0.0.0:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://0.0.0.0:3000/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4
Cookie: scottysid=1CVBcS09G4PKktG8XkyPHu8JjBj0FmhaltjmIprX
```

Body:

```
{"local":false,"uname":"Foo","pass":"Bar"}
```

Response headers:

```
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 15 Sep 2014 07:40:45 GMT
Server:Warp/3.0.1.1
```

Comment: I would debug the issue using POSTMan chrome add-on, curl, Charles Web Debugging Proxy and or the network panel to try to get more info.  Not the same exact problem but something similar here too https://github.com/andygill/blank-canvas/issues/4

Comment: @shaunhusain Looking at the Chromes console it shows proper POST headers and proper body. But from the Scotty side it looks like I get just empty body. I removed the `jsonData` function and just trying to print the body - I get nothing. Weird.

Comment: yeah sorry not familiar with haskell or scotty so not sure where to point you for further debugging