# Scotty, WAI: Capturing request body

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp, scotty

I don't seem to be able to capture request body any more.
Everything started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840699/haskell-scotty-and-angularjs-jsondata-function-stopped-parsing-json-data-sent-w) when I hit the problem after an update.
I was trying to investigate it and got to a point where I cant get the request body niether with scotty's `body` function nor with Network.WAI functions on which Scotty builds.
I could probably parse the json body myself only if I could get it.

I am trying this and it does not work. I just get an empty bytestring.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import           Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import           Web.Scotty.Trans
import           Network.Wai (requestBody)

loginUser :: ActionD ()
loginUser = do
  r <- request
  b <- liftIO $ requestBody r
  if C.null b then error "Empty" else error ("Body: " ++ (C.unpack b))
```

So what am I doing wrong to catch the request body? What changes have been made to Scotty recently so that it stop working as usual?

Thanks

Comment: Are you building from cabal sandbox or global packages? Which versions of scotty, wai and warp are you currently building against? On which platform?

Comment: @shang Building on Arch Linux. All package versions are the latest cabal update pool. Building in sandbox.